# Find the ratio $\frac{R}{r}$ rounded to four decimals

Tags: geometry

> A large circle of radius R is surrounded by 12 smaller circles of radius r. Find the ratio $\frac{R}{r}$ rounded to four decimals.
>
> Hint: Draw an isosceles triangle with one vertex at the centre of the R-circle
> and the other vertices at the centres of two adjacent r-circles.

[image: circles]

I drew the triangle, and the two equal sides (let's call them A and B) have a length of $R + r$, and the different side (let's call it C) has a length of $2r$.

I understand that the angle AB is 30 degrees (I divided 360 by 12), and as it's an isosceles triangle the other two angles are equal. They both measure 75 degrees.

I don't understand how to calculate the ratio though.

Comment: Each of the two smaller circles is tangent to the larger circle. Connect those points with a line and you have a similar triangle.

Comment: Your working has everything you need. You can check the right angled triangle made by tangent from center of larger circle to one of the smaller circles and  perpendicular to it from the center of the smaller circle. So you have $r = (R+r) \sin 15^0$ and that should lead you to the ratio.

Comment: @MathLover How do you know that the tangency point segment to the small circle center is perpendicular?

Comment: Just using the fact that line from center of the circle to the tangent point is perpendicular to the tangent line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the law of sines.
\begin{align}
\frac{2r}{\sin{30^\circ}}&=\frac{R+r}{\sin75^\circ}\\
2r\sin75^\circ&=(R+r)\sin30^\circ\\
2r\left(\frac{\sqrt2+\sqrt6}4\right)&=(R+r)\left(\frac12\right)\\
(\sqrt2+\sqrt6)r&=R+r\\
(\sqrt2+\sqrt6-1)r&=R\\
\frac{R}r&=\sqrt2+\sqrt6-1\approx2.8637
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The centers of circles and one of the point of tangency of two smaller circles determine a right triangle with $90,75,15$

$$\sin 15=\frac{r}{R+r}$$

$$\frac{R+r}{r}=\frac{1}{\sin 15}$$

$$\frac{R}{r}=\frac{1}{\sin 15}-1=\sqrt2+\sqrt6-1$$
where
$$\sin 15=\frac{\sqrt6-\sqrt2}{4}$$

Comment: How do you know that angle is 90 degrees?

Comment: Radius of smaller circle is perpendicular to tangent

Comment: Right, but how do you know they are perpendicular? Now that you mentioned it I see it, but I don't understand how I could have figured it out.

Comment: See this https://brilliant.org/wiki/tangent-perpendicular-to-radius/#:~:text=A%20tangent%20to%20a%20circle,perpendicular%20to%20the%20tangent%20line.

Comment: The shortest distance from center to point of tangency is radius.